# SMS gateways and 3G obsolescence

Tags: sms, mms

Yesterday I received the email below from my cellular provider informing me that my Huawei E1786 would stop working by January 2021. I currently use this device to send/receive sms messages and to receive MMS messages-- the modem receives the hex code then establishes a broadband connection and downloads the picture/file. If all 3G devices and all devices that lack the Voice over LTE technology stop working does this mean will Gammu become obsolete in the next month? I do not know of any 5G or even 4G devices -- certainly not any modems -- that work with Gammu does anyone else know of any?

> Dear Richard,
>
> We’re reaching out to warn you that the major US carriers are on the
> verge of shutting down their older networks in favor of newer LTE and
> 5G networks.
>
> From January 2021, older devices including your E1786 lack the Voice
> over LTE (VoLTE) technology to connect over these newer networks and
> will stop working completely with most carriers. Your device could
> begin to experience issues even sooner.

Comment: You should still be able to use the device’s 2G (GSM) featureset. The message about VoLTE is just autogenerated from a database I guess. It’s not a phone anyway.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for the reply. I hope you are right.

Comment: This looks like it will affect all 2G and 3G devices and not just phones. https://www.ttnews.com/articles/3g-cellular-network-sunsetting-raises-concerns-trucking